# Is there an ESLint rule to align `=` on assignments

Tags: eslint

I'm looking for a rule which aligns all `=` on assignments.

Something like this would be positive:

```
var foo       = 12;
var barfoo    = 21;
var barfoobar = 22;
```

Something like this would be negative:

```
var foo = 12;
var barfoobar = 21;
```

Rubocop has a rule called `ForceEqualSignAlignment` for exactly this. I wonder if there is something like that for `ESLint`?

Comment: [It doesn't seem like there's a core ESLint rule for that](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11025), since it's not a popular standard in the JS world (unfortunately). Someone will have to write a custom plugin to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-align-assignments. It works well.

Unfortunately it seems to conflict with no-multi-spaces because of the spaces in front of the variable name.

```
let   a1 = 2;    // (no-multi-spaces) Multiple spaces found before 'a1'.
const a  = a1;
const b  = a;
```

Comment: If you combine it with the other comment `/*eslint no-multi-spaces: ["error", { exceptions: { "VariableDeclarator": true } }]*/` the two don't fight and you have what you want I think.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's no such rule in ESlint, there's [a workaround](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces) to allow manual alignment in JS:

```js
/*eslint no-multi-spaces: ["error", { exceptions: { "VariableDeclarator": true } }]*/

var someVar      = 'foo';
var someOtherVar = 'barBaz';
```